# How to add single quote and comma to all values in a column?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a column `host` with following values:

```
server1.abc.com
server2.abc.com
server3
```

Now, I want each of these values to be single quotes and separated by comma. The output should be like as below:

```
'server1.abc.com','server2.abc.com','server3'
```

Please let me know how this can be achieved using Excel.

So far I am able to separate values using `,` with following code:

```
Public Function MergeME(r As Range) As String
  MergeME = Join(Application.Transpose(r.Value), ",")
End Function
```

How can I add double quotes around values in each cell??

Comment: Are you after double quotes or single quotes?  There is a **slight** difference in the answers based on what you want.  (Double quotes have to be escaped in strings, single quotes don't.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your original UDF was close. You just need to join with `','` rather than `,` and then place `'` at the start and end of your output string

```
Public Function MergeME(r As Range) As String
  MergeME = "'" & Join(Application.Transpose(r.Value), "','") & "'"
End Function
```

Output string as required:

```
'server1.abc.com','server2.abc.com','server3'
```

Comment: Just curious to know how `','` makes difference

Comment: @me24hour, `JOIN({a,b,c},"*")` returns the string: `a*b*c` so it follows that `JOIN({a,b,c},"','")` returns `a','b','c` so all that remains is to add the apostrophes at the beginning and end

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1** through **A3**, in **B1** enter:

```
="'"
```

(*this is a single quote encased in double quotes*)

Then in **B2**:

```
=B1 & A1 & B1 & "," & B1 & A2 & B1 & "," & B1 & A3 & B1
```

[image]

Comment: How can I modify the formula to account for `1000 values in Column` **A**?

Comment: I have edited my question and added a UDF that separates values using comma. I need help to add double quotes around it.

Comment: select column A and use edit / replace and replace ',' with "," or " ',' " depending what you need.

Answer (score -1):

NO functions or VBA are needed

```
In cell B1 input this = CHAR(39)
In cell C1 input this ,
In cell D1 = CONCAT($B$1,A1,$B$1,$C$1)
In cell D2 = CONCAT(D1,$B$1,A2,$B$1,$C$1)
```

from D2 - D(x) this is automated you can copy Cell D2 to Cell D3 yielding this:

```
in cell D3 = CONCAT(D2,$B$1,A3,$B$1,$C$1)
```

YOU COULD FIND THE LARGEST LENGTH in the Dx column via lookup and then get your final output string; i didn't do that here-- i added the following:

```
In cell E3 = LEN(D3)
```

i take the final comma out:

```
In cell F2 = LEFT(D3,E3-1)
```

very automated task