# Excel VBA - String Conactenation with delimiter and single quotes

Tags: vba, excel, string-concatenation, textjoin

I have a column of cells. They need to be concatenated into a single string with multiple delimiters in between.

I need something like the result in column 2 from the values in column 1

```
Column 1 | column 2
a1       |   'a1'
a2       |    'a1';'a2'
a3       |    'a1';'a2';'a3'
a4       |    'a1';'a2';'a3';'a4'
a5       |    'a1';'a2';'a3';'a4';'a5'
```

Currently I use the following formula

```
Column 1  |   Column 2
a1        |  ="'"&a1&"'"&";"
a2        |  =b1&"'"&a2&"'"&";"
a3        |
```

and copy it down the column B2.

Is there a VBA code that could help me do that. I did find some that would add a single delimiter ' between the cells but I could not modify it to add multiple delimiters.

It would be very helpful could share a VBA code for the same.

Comment: Yes there probably is.

Comment: If you are using Excel 2016, the `TEXTJOIN` function is all you would need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add single quote and comma to all values in a column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42915255/how-to-add-single-quote-and-comma-to-all-values-in-a-column)

Comment: Just asked and answered three times at [Excel VBA UDF for concatenating is giving an Error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004691/excel-vba-udf-for-concatenating-is-giving-an-error-message/43005063#43005063).

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help. I will try all these methods and let you know which worked the best for me. Thanks again for everyone for all your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Join` method in VBA with a given delimeter:

e.g.

```
someArray = Array("some", "words", "here")
Debug.Print "'" & Join(someArray, "';'") & "'"

'// will print:
'// 'some';'words';'here'
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked for VBA, but you can do this with a formula:

In `B2`:

```
=IF(ROW()=2,TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,"'"&B1,"'"&A2&"'"),TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,B1,"'"&A2&"'"))
```

and drag down:

[image]

Or

In `B1`, use `="'"&A1&"'"`, then in `B2` (and drag down):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,"'"&B1,"'"&A2&"'"),"'","",1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve desired output using this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(B2, " ; '", A3, "'")
```

First put value from cell A2 to B2 manually (using `="'" & A2 & "'"` formula) and then paste this formula in cell B3 and drag it down.

Here is the result with updated formula:

[image]

**UPDATE** (*Thanks to BruceWayne*)

Enter the value in cell B2 using:

```
="'" & A2 & "'"
```

So it will take the first **`'`**

Comment: That seems to just repeat the `A` column value, instead of using the current row, plus the previous rows.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ah nice, this a bit is better than mine :D . Just to note, I'd change `B2` to `="'"&A1&"'"` to get the very first `'` leading `a1'`.

Comment: Ah good catch again. I don't somehow I missed it. I think I need coffee now. :D

Answer (score 1):

I would just do a simple loop like so.

```
Sub combineRows()

    'start and end rows, assuming column A
    Dim startRow, endRow As Integer

    Dim myString, myAdd As String

    startRow = 2
    endRow = 6



    For i = startRow To endRow


        myAdd = "'" & Range("A" & i) & "'" & ";"

        myString = myString + myAdd

        Range("B" & i) = myString

    Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for this simple code. It is pretty easy. However I am having two problems.
1. The first ' is missing for the first entry in all rows
2. A ";" is remaining after the last entry in all rows

Can you please help me with this is issue?
Why is it happening? Can it be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's my `JoinRange` function. It has a few more options than you're looking for.

```
Public Function JoinRange(rInput As Range, _
     Optional sDelim As String = vbNullString, _
     Optional sLineStart As String = vbNullString, _
     Optional sLineEnd As String = vbNullString, _
     Optional sBlank As String = vbNullString, _
     Optional sQuotes As String = vbNullString, _
     Optional IgnoreBlanks As Boolean = True) As String

     Dim vaCells As Variant
     Dim i As Long, j As Long
     Dim lCnt As Long
     Dim aReturn() As String

     If rInput.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim aReturn(1 To 1)
        aReturn(1) = sQuotes & rInput.Value & sQuotes
     Else
        vaCells = rInput.Value
         ReDim aReturn(1 To rInput.Cells.Count)

         For i = LBound(vaCells, 1) To UBound(vaCells, 1)
             For j = LBound(vaCells, 2) To UBound(vaCells, 2)
                 If Len(vaCells(i, j)) = 0 Then
                     If Not IgnoreBlanks Then
                         lCnt = lCnt + 1
                         aReturn(lCnt) = sQuotes & sBlank & sQuotes
                     End If
                 Else
                     lCnt = lCnt + 1
                     aReturn(lCnt) = sQuotes & vaCells(i, j) & sQuotes
                 End If
             Next j
         Next i

         ReDim Preserve aReturn(1 To lCnt)
     End If

     JoinRange = sLineStart & Join(aReturn, sDelim) & sLineEnd

End Function
```

use it in B1 like

```
=JoinRange($A$1:A1,";")
```

and fill down.

Comment: Hi, 
I tried the code but it is not adding the leading and ending single quote (')
Can you please point out what I am missing?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the quotes. Use it like `=JoinRange($A$1:A1,";",,,,"'")`. That last argument is double quote - single quote - double quote.

Comment: Note also that I updated the code to fix a bug where a single cell range didn't get handled properly.

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>For the sake of avoiding visual confusion, I will offer `CHAR(39)&CHAR(59)&CHAR(39)` in place of `"';'"`.</sub>

In B1, use this:

```
=CHAR(39)&TEXTJOIN(CHAR(39)&CHAR(59)&CHAR(39), TRUE, A$1:A1)&CHAR(39)
```

Fill down.

[image: ![enter image description here]

... or if the end result is the only important thing,

```
=CHAR(39)&TEXTJOIN(CHAR(39)&CHAR(59)&CHAR(39), TRUE, A1:A5)&CHAR(39)
```

[image]

A single tick (*aka* single quote or `'`) is ASCII character 39 and a semi-colon is ASCII character 59.